# Why doesn't Alpine.js work with all events from their examples?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying out Alpine.js, but some of the examples doesn't work for me. For example

```html
<button x-on:click="alert('Hello World!')">Say Hi</button>
```

This doesn't alert anything.

```html
<button x-on:click="console.log('test')">Log</button>
```

And this doesn't log anything into the console. However other things work:

```html
<div x-data="{ count: 0 }">
    <button x-on:click="count--">Decrement</button>
    <code>count: </code><code x-text="count"></code>
    <button x-on:click="count++">Increment</button>
</div>
```

This is my whole page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Works</h1>

<div x-data="{ count: 0 }">
    <button x-on:click="count--">Decrement</button>
    <code>count: </code><code x-text="count"></code>
    <button x-on:click="count++">Increment</button>
</div>

<div x-data="{ open: false }">
    <button @click="open = ! open">Expand</button>

    <div x-show="open">
        Content...
    </div>
</div>

<div x-data="{ title: 'Start Here' }">
    <h1 x-text="title"></h1>
</div>

<button x-data="{ label: 'Click Here' }" x-text="label"></button>


<h1>Doesn't work</h1>

<button x-on:click="console.log('test')">Log</button>

<button x-on:click="alert('Hello World!')">Say Hi</button>

<button @click="$event.target.remove()">Remove Me</button>

<div @foo="console.log('foo was dispatched')">
    <button @click="$dispatch('foo')">Dispatch</button>
</div>


<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples that aren't working don't have an x-data attribute (either on themselves or a parent). Whether there's data or not, the `x-data` attribute is required to get AlpineJS functionality.

If you wrap the entire "Doesn't work" section in a `<div x-data></div>` they should work:

```
<div x-data>
    <button x-on:click="console.log('test')">Log</button>

    <button x-on:click="alert('Hello World!')">Say Hi</button>

    <button @click="$event.target.remove()">Remove Me</button>

    <div @foo="console.log('foo was dispatched')">
        <button @click="$dispatch('foo')">Dispatch</button>
    </div>
</div>
```